# How do I code a rake task that runs the Rails db:migrate task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I would like to run db:migrate VERSION=0 and then db:migrate inside of my own rake task.  I am confused about how to do this.  Do I need a special require statement?   My rake task will reside in the lib/tasks directory of a Rails app.   Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your task just dependent on having a clean db? If that's the case then you can do:

task :my_task => [:environment, 'db:reset']

Comment: Okay I like this.   It works.  This must surely mean that the :environment task loads all the rails rake namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Rake::Task[] won't accept parameters, you have to set it in ENV.  In addition, you have to reenable the task to run it multiple times.

```
ENV['VERSION']= '0'
Rake::Task['db:migrate'].invoke
Rake::Task['db:migrate'].reenable
ENV.delete 'VERSION'
Rake::Task["db:migrate"].invoke
```

NOTE: Rake::Task.reenable requires Rake 0.8.2 or higher.

Comment: I tried this inside of my custom rake task (residing in lib/tasks) but it failed.   ("rake aborted Don't know how to build task db:migrate VERSION=0")

Comment: Rake::Task[] does accept params:  Rake::Task['my:task'].invoke("123-abc")

Answer (score 0):

Check out `rake db:reset` as that will accomplish what you are trying to do.

To see what all of your rake tasks do, run `rake -T`

Comment: This is interesting but it does not really explain how to run a pre-built rails task inside of a newly created custom rake task.

Comment: Yep, since Pesto got his answer in before mine, I figured it wouldn't hurt to show you an easier way even though it didn't answer the question exactly.