# Execute a Rake task from within migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I have a Rake task that loads configuration data into the DB from a file, is there a correct ruby/rails way to call it on a migration up?

My objective is to sync my team DB configs, **without have to broadcast then to run the task** *lalala*

```
  def self.up
    change_table :fis_situacao_fiscal do |t|
      t.remove :mostrar_endereco
      t.rename :serie, :modelo 
    end

    Faturamento::Cfop.destroy_all()
    #perform rake here !
  end
```

**UPDATE**
How I do now, and works:

```
system('rake sistema:load_data file=faturamento/cfop')
```

And this is the suggestion from **@Ryan Bigg**, and it's exception:

```
Rake::Task['rake sistema:load_data file=faturamento/cfop'].invoke()
```

.

```
==  AlterSituacaoFiscalModeloEndereco: migrating ====================
-- change_table(:fis_situacao_fiscal)
   -> 0.0014s

rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Don't know how to build task 'rake sistema:load_data file=faturamento/cfop'
```

Where it went wrong?

Comment: Why would you pass the word "rake" in? Try it without it. It knows it's a rake task.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Yes! There is a way to do that.

Run the following command.

```rb
Rake::Task['your_task'].invoke
```

### Updated solution

Do not put Rake inside parenthesis, just the *name* of the task. I recommend that you set an `ENV` variable when running the following in the console.

```rb
FILE=somefile.text rake db:sistema:load_data
```

You can call it separately using the following example.

```rb
FILE=somefile.text rake some:other:task:that:calls:it
```

It will be available in your tasks as `ENV['file']`.

Comment: I made an update with your answer, glad if you could help some more

Comment: What if the task is in a namespace? I have a seed system that can be run with `rake semi:seed[89]` (will run the .rb file starting with `89_`), but I can't invoke it with `Rake::Task['semi:seed[89]']` Do you have an idea on how I could invoke the seed task in a migration file?

Comment: My bad, I just had to pass the `89` args in the invoke: `Rake::Task['semi:seed'].invoke('89')` works fine

Comment: Did anybody else get `You have 1 pending migrations:`. It won't allow another rake task to be run in the middle of a migration.

Comment: if you don't know your tasks' name run `rake -T -A` to get a full list

Answer (score 10):

Note that if you call the Rake task with 'system', you need to check the process status afterwards and raise an exception if the Rake task failed. Otherwise the migration will succeed even if the Rake task fails.

You can check the process status like this:

```
if !($?.success?)
  raise "Rake task failed"
end
```

Invoking the rake task is a nicer option - it will cause the migration to fail if the Rake task fails.

Answer (score 7):

You can execute a rake task from within a loaded Rails environment with either `Rake::Task['namespace:task'].invoke` or `Rake::Task['namespace:task'].execute`.

You can pass data to the task inside of the `invoke` or `execute` method. Example:

```
Rake::Task['namespace:task'].invoke(paramValue)
```

This param can be handled in the rake task as follows:

```
namespace :namespace do
  desc "Example description."
  task :task, [:param] => :environment do |t, args|
    puts args[:param]
    ...
  end
end
```

This can be executed on the console as:

```
bundle exec rake namespace:task[paramValue]
```

More info: https://medium.com/@sampatbadhe/rake-task-invoke-or-execute-419cd689c3bd

Answer (score 1):

[This decision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/611230/9880854) fits better, IMHO.

In your case it would be smth like this:

```
backup_env = ENV.slice('file') if ENV.key?('file')
ENV['file'] = 'faturamento/cfop'
Rake::Task['sistema:load_data'].invoke
ENV.delete 'file'
ENV.merge!(backup_env) if backup_env
```