# Heroku database rake with loop

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake

I am trying to run this migration on heroku, but it hangs at the loop.

```
puts "0"
add_column :batches, :store_id, :integer
add_column :batches, :company_id, :integer
puts "1"
for batch in Batch.all()
    puts "2"
    batch.company_id = batch.register.store.company.id.to_i
    puts "3"
    batch.store_id = batch.register.store.id.to_i
    puts "4"
    batch.save
    puts "5"
end
puts "6"
```

Unfortunately, I can't tell exactly where it is hanging because none of my "puts" are being shown in console.  The last line I get is:

```
 -- add_column(:batches, :store_id, :integer)
```

I am not able to get any migrations with a loop working on heroku, but they all work fine locally, am I doing something wrong?

Output from heroku logs:

```
2011-06-20T13:58:15+00:00 app[rake.14]: Starting process with command `rake db:migrate --trace`
2011-06-20T13:58:48+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGTERM
2011-06-20T13:58:48+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Stopping ...
2011-06-20T13:58:48+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably because you are not including the environment which I show below; you can also run this in heroku console

`In your apps shell/terminal`

```
heroku console
```

Then just run it as a block because heroku will not let you run do/end blocks

```
Batch.all.each {|b| b.update_attributes(:company => b.register.store.company, :store => b.register.store)}
```

So that should work in console unless one of those fields is nill and that is why you are going to need a rake task for erros.

Try this instead:

`lib/tasks/add_bathces.rake`

```
task :add_bathces => :environment do 
  Batch.all.each do |batch|
    if batch.register.store.comapny &&  batch.register.store
        batch.update_attributes(:company => b.register.store.company, :store => b.register.store)
    else
      puts "Store or company were nill"
    end
  end  
end
```

Comment: is there a way to then call this task from within a migration? or is this type of data manipulation completely outside the realm of heroku migrations?

Comment: sh#t, that was for raking it.

Comment: You can call it from a migration.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632138/execute-a-rake-task-from-within-migration

Comment: something to do with your db then. I do this stuff all the time.

Comment: Where should I start looking for the DB error? Seems weird that it goes locally without a hitch.  It looks like it crashed my whole app.

Comment: It's probably something to do with you using sqlite on your local machine and heroku defaulting to postgres.

Comment: Start with installing and using postgres locally and see if you can still rake, hopefully development will catch the error causing the problem.

Comment: Looks like I can't access the Batch model after making changes to it... I added Batch.reset_column_information to no avail.

Comment: The problem is definitely some combination of postgre and rails models.  I can't access the Batch model after making changes to that table.  It does work if I use straight SQL (which is ugly as eff).